# Merge Sort MIPS Unknown Amount of User Input

Tags: assembly, mips, mergesort

I am trying to develop my assembly coding skills for the h*ck of it, and I'm trying to challenge myself by creating Merge Sort because my fiend friend said I couldn't do it, but the amount of numbers in the array is unknown to the program.

I stored the user input until I type in a "-1" into the command line (or if the array is full, but I made it a large array as you can see).

I've looked at other versions of Merge Sort, including the one found [here](https://gist.github.com/jmc734/6630563), but he/she assumes an array of a certain size filled with integers, and that's not what I'm trying to do.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    .data
array:  .space 4096
string: .asciiz "Enter #s - -1 stops input: \n"

.text
.globl main

main:
   la $s0, array
   la $s1, ($s0)
   la $a0, string
   li $v0, 4
   syscall

   move $t0, $zero

readInput:
   beq $t0, 4096, setSize
   li $v0, 5
   syscall
   beq $v0, -1, setSize
   sw $v0, 0($s0)
   addi $s0, $s0, 4
   addi $t0, $t0, 4
   j readInput

setSize:
   add $s2, $s1, $t0
   j printUnsortedArray

printUnsortedArray:
    # here is where I want to print it unsorted, first

mergeSort:
   # I have a pretty good idea of how to do the algorithm, but I do
   # not know how to start it off with what I have/what I still need
   # to implement
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly so I can move to a different assembly idea with a peace of mind.

PS - You're not my friend anymore. You know who you are, fiend.

Comment: So what is the question? You know how many numbers you stored. At the moment you are counting bytes in `$t0`, but that can be easily changed to words.

Comment: First question: How do I print the unsorted array? Second: What's the best way to start implementing the recursive Merge Sort algorithm?

Comment: You can print the unsorted array in any way you wish. Which way do you want it to show? Pick one, then code it. Best way to implement merge sort is to use some well written working library, to avoid own mistakes and bugs and ineffectiveness. For example from performance point of view most of the time it is better to avoid recursion by turning it into loop (quite often even the code isn't lot more more complex than the recursion variant one, especially in assembly, where recursion is actually a bit of mundane task to write, having to store/restore everything on stack).

Comment: Have you tried writing it in C and looking at compiler output?  Printing the array is obviously going to be something like reading the array, using a SPIM/Mars syscall for each element would be the obvious way.  You know how many elements you have, because you counted them as you read them.